# Why is a verb before a 格助詞 called 連体形?

Tags: grammar

As I have known, 格助詞 is not 体言.That is what I cannot understand.

Comment: You're probably talking about 準体助詞「の」 used like 「走る**の**が遅い」, right?

Comment: Well, I have to give an example then:「間違えたに決まっている」.It seems to occur mostly with に and より.